# Can Static (FBML) Facebook fanpage access user's UID & Profile pic?

Tags: facebook

I know UIDs and profile pics can be accessed via Facebook app but can the same be done on Static FBML pages? I want to be able to submit a form with the UID information and also be able to post Fan's profile pic on the fan page with out using Facebook Application.
Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not.  To access this information you must use an application.

Comment: Appreciate it Daryl. Another individual mentioned the following:
In order to capture user data from a tab, you need to pass an "Allow Access" screen asking for basic info. 

In order to do this from an FBJS AJAX call, simply add requireLogin=true to the AJAX object. 

E.g.:function form_submit(form) {  var ajax = new Ajax();   ajax.responseType = Ajax.FBML;  ajax.requireLogin = true;  ajax.ondone = function(data) {    ...  }  ajax.onerror = function(data) {    ...  }  ajax.post(form.getAction(), form.serialize());}

What do you think about that?

Comment: I've used FBJS before and as far as I know you still have to have a registered application for the FB JS to work with user data.  The allow access screen will reference your registered application's icon and information and present it to the user.